# How do I use a randomy generated API key on a SPA?

Tags: javascript, html, api, single-page-application

I'm making a pure vanilla JS and HTML SPA where you log in, authenticate against an API, and once you are authenticated you can access a service where you upload a CSV file to be corrected.

My question is, how do I store the randomly generated API key evertime a user logs in? The API key needs to be stored so that they can access the service which also relies on an API call.

EDIT: Here's the code.

```
<form class="form" id="myForm">

    <label for="username">Username</label>

    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">

    <label for="password">Password</label>

    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">

    <button type="submit>">LogIn</button>

</form>

<script>

    // Authentication.
    const myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

    myForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const formData = new FormData(this);
        const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();

        for (const pair of formData) {
            searchParams.append(pair[0], pair[1]);
        }

        fetch('https://placeholder.com/api/Authentication/Authenticate', {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            hostname: 'placeholder.com',
            port: null,
            path: `/api/Authentication/Authenticate?username=${username}&password=${password}`,
            headers: {
                "accept":"application/json"
                // "apiKey": ""
            },
            body: searchParams,
            json: true
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.text();
        }).then(function (text) {
            console.log(text);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        })
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are different ways to achieve this.

If you want your API key to be accessible on different sessions (e.g. if the user leaves the SPA and comes back after some time), you can use [the local storage of the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Otherwise, you can have a variable set at the root of your JS and assign it the API key that you get once you log in. This way, your variable will be accessible everywhere in your JS because its context is the global context or your JS.

**Edited 04/09/21, 2:37pm:**

Here could be a way to do it:

```js
// Authentication.
    const myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
    let apiKey;

    myForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const formData = new FormData(this);
        const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();

        for (const pair of formData) {
            searchParams.append(pair[0], pair[1]);
        }

        fetch('https://placeholder.com/api/Authentication/Authenticate', {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            hostname: 'placeholder.com',
            port: null,
            path: `/api/Authentication/Authenticate?username=${username}&password=${password}`,
            headers: {
                "accept":"application/json"
                // "apiKey": ""
            },
            body: searchParams,
            json: true
        }).then(function (response) {
            apiKey = response.data.key; // Use the appropriate response property here.

            // You can call any function using apiKey from here.
            nextAction();
            
            return response.text();
        }).then(function (text) {
            console.log(text);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        })
    });
    
    const nextAction = () => {
      console.log(apiKey); // apiKey should be set here.
      return;
    }
```

```html
<form class="form" id="myForm">

    <label for="username">Username</label>

    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">

    <label for="password">Password</label>

    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">

    <button type="submit>">LogIn</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! The second option sounds perfect, the only problem is I'm not sure how to actually get the API key from the data of the API response into the variable at the root?

Comment: Can you share your code, so I could give you a hint?

Comment: I edited my answer to. Let me know if this works for you.